# Angular, why is my injectable component not ready when I try to use it?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

When a component is initalized, I inject some initial support components into it. These are injected using the providedIn: root. I want these components to wait till the constructor which has an http scribe in it to finish. Suppose I have a component like this

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SomeService {
    constructor(){
        .... calls http service and subscribes uses response for setup of class variables for use later
        .... does a bunch of stuff and takes a little while
    }
    useThisService(){
       ... accesses something set up in constructor
    }
}
```

and then I use it like this:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(private service: SomeService){}
    ngOnInit(): void{
       service.useThisService() //returns an error because the constructor of SomeService was still getting set up
    }
}
```

How do I make angular wait till that injectable item is done being constructed before I use it? I have tried to use @Output() event emitter and it seems to work, but isn't there some method with less overhead than having to subscribe to output events in order to complete a dependency tree?

Comment: What is the constructor inside the SomeService doing exactly?

Comment: It is just calling a backend api to initialize some variables like userid teamid etc. These are needed by other portions of the UI on startup.

Comment: The ctor is always executed first... What you're looking for is to await the HTTP response in the CTOR, before executing the `useThisService` method. You'll have to add waiting logic to the `useThisService` before executing the next part of the logic, you'll probably want to return an observable with the `useThisService`

Comment: @JamesD what about adding waiting logic to the constructor? I haven't even thought about doing this. You said that the constructor is always executed first? well if I have it wait for that http response to come back inside the constructor, I guess it wouldn't be able to use member variables till then

Comment: @coloradoman HTTP calls are async, they won't block other code from being executed... You must validate if the HTTP call is finalized in your other methods by storing its state in an observable for instance, and when the other methods are called validate if that state allows execution of the next part or wait until completion.

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you're actually doing in the constructor? Is it a login/postdata/getdata/...? If so have you checked out https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request in detail?

Comment: @JamesD can you see my proposed answer below. It is interesting, not sure if it would work.

Comment: Can you add what data you are actually waiting for? Is it a login, because then it would make sense to page switch upon receiving the HTTP response for instance

Comment: @JamesD Its not login, its just a bunch of user data that is loaded after redirect from login.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing has changed yet, it is NOT supported to eg return `Promise` as dependency factory (only app initializer supports that) so you have to delay usage of your dependency yourself.

Example of such delay would be like

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SomeService {
    public $ready=new BehaviorSubject<boolean>();
    constructor(){
       //do your thing, call whatever you want and do the following after everythoing is done and service is ready to be used

      this.$ready.next(true);
    }
    useThisService(){
       ... accesses something set up in constructor
    }
}


export class SomeComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(private service: SomeService){}
    ngOnInit(): void{
       this.someService.pipe(
         filter(v=>v),
         take(1)
       ).subscribe(()=>{
            service.useThisService(); // now it will work
       })
       
    }
}
```

Comment: really? I have to actually use a wait in the components that depend on this? Isn't there someway to tell angular to wait till something in this class has a value?

Comment: This is what I wrote.

Comment: what do you think of the way I posted below?

Comment: Thats what i wrote,app initializer supports that. And if you are ok with delaying startup of your application it is fine.

Comment: Yes, the app depends on the setUpService() method in order to run properly. It should be delayed till it is set up.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just used the providers functionality in angular

```
function initializeApp(init: SomeService) {
    return () => init.setUpService();
}
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...declarations],
    imports: [ ...imports],
    providers:[
        SomeService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initializeApp,
            deps: [SomeService],
            multi: true,
        }
    ]
})
```

and then make a method in the SomeService that returns an observable that contains any kind of long process or http call

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SomeService {
    constructor(){
    }
    setUpService(){
        //calls http service and subscribes uses response for setup of class variables for use later
        //Important! returns an observable
        return http.get('url').subscribe(response =>{
           .... does a bunch of stuff and takes a little while
        })
    }
    useThisService(){
       ... accesses something set up by http response
    }
}
```